# Forward Selection and Backward Elimination

Tags: regression, data-analysis

I am analyzing some data. I have 7 features and want to predict y. I performed a forward selection and a backward elimination but both models are yielding very bad results. I generated more features through transformation of the x variables (x^2, x^3, 1/x, x^(1/2)) to see if the results get better (so 28 variables in total)
After running the code I get even worst results, no matter what I do (adjust significance level, change elimination criteria) , I always get the intercept as regression function in the forward selection and all variables (normal and transformed) in the backward elimination.

Do you have an idea why this is happening? As far as I understand, in the case of forward selection, the algorithm checks the p-values of each variable and adds the best one. so if in the first case (without transformed variables) x1 is in the regression function, in the second case (with transformed variables) x1 should also be in the regression function rather than the function being just the intercept.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is your dependent (y) [correlated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) with any of your independent or generated x features?
How are you evaluating the model, the `R-squared` is a popular metric. A value closer to 1 may indicate a better model as your chosen x variables are good at explaining the change (predicting) y. A better metric may be your `Adjusted R Squared` as this will have a lower value if you use more x variables and would be greater or closer to `R Squared` if you use less x variables.

Some code or a tool would help in providing a more specific response.

Furthermore, you are using regression analysis. There are many types which utilize different assumptions. Even so, sometimes regression analysis may not be the algorithm of choice to develop an ideal model